# Object passing using Pipes in C++

Tags: c++, operating-system, pipe

```
class Proc
{
public:
    string schedulingAlgo;
    string procName;
    int quantum;
    int arrivalTime;
    int burstTime;
}
```

This is my class whose object i want to pass to another process using pipes using the write sys call

```
write(fd_admit_write,(char*)&procs, sizeof((char*)&procs));
```

And in the other process, I am trying to read this and convert it back into the Proc type using this

```
char buffer[15];
read(fd_admit_read,buffer,15);
Proc *pp = reinterpret_cast<Proc *>(buffer);
```

I know that the method I used for conversion is fine because I tried it independently but when I use it in pipes, the output of **pp** gets distorted.

Comment: Because strings contain pointers internally it's not possible to serialize them this way. It doesn't work within a process (you must have just got lucky) but it absolutely isn't going to work when sent to another process.

Comment: Proc * pp = reinterpret_cast<Proc *>((char*)&procs);
This works fine

Comment: I really doubt it.

Comment: It is working, I've tried it multiple times, also if there is some other way please tell

Comment: It's simple to do, write the length of the string followed by it's characters, then read the same at the other end.

Comment: Its not a string, its an object of Procs which i have to pass in pipe

Comment: And `Procs` consists of two strings and the integers. Write each string seperately, followed by the three integers.

Comment: If you are looking for a one line of code solution then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes do not share memory (generally). They do not see each others' memory. That is, you cannot have a pointer to a memory address in another process.

As far as I understand, you are sending a `Proc*` to another process. While `Proc*` points to a valid `Proc` object in the sending process, it will point to uninitialized memory in the receiving process. You have to actually send all the data needed for constructing a `Proc` object, and construct it on the receiver side.

Even if you sent the `Proc` object itself instead of a pointer to it, it would not work, because it has a string member variable, and a string contains a pointer to its data (except in case of small string optimization).

You can use a good binary protocol like [msgpack](https://msgpack.org/) or implement your own serialization/deserialization based on your needs.

Comment: I tried it using write(fd_admit_write, &procs, sizeof(procs)) and this worked

Comment: Try bigger strings (length > 50 for example)